# activejdbc with aws Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, activejdbc

I am unable to get activejdbc working with aws serverless.

I added my connection params as ENV variables and Base.findAll() works, but I am unable to get the models to work, i get the following error

```
"org.javalite.activejdbc.InitException: you are trying to work with models, but no models are found. Maybe you have no models in project, or you did not instrument the models. It is expected that you have a file activejdbc_models.properties on classpath\n\tat org.javalite.activejdb
```

I checked my jar file, and it does have a 'activejdbc_models.properties' file, and the instrumentation seems to have worked.

Is this path a dead end? should I just shift to direct jdbc? or can I get actveJDBC to work with lambda.

Update
Ran javap on one of my model classes Address, here is the output

```
Compiled from "Address.java"
public class com.kwiqhealth.models.Address extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model {
  public com.kwiqhealth.models.Address();
  public static org.javalite.activejdbc.MetaModel getMetaModel();
  public static org.javalite.activejdbc.MetaModel metaModel();
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T findOrCreateIt(java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T findOrInit(java.lang.Object...);
  public static java.util.Set<java.lang.String> attributeNames();
  public static java.util.List<org.javalite.activejdbc.associations.Association> associations();
  public static int delete(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static boolean exists(java.lang.Object);
  public static int deleteAll();
  public static int update(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static int updateAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.NumericValidationBuilder validateNumericalityOf(java.lang.String...);
  public static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder addValidator(org.javalite.validation.Validator);
  protected static void addScope(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  public static void removeValidator(org.javalite.validation.Validator);
  public static java.util.List<org.javalite.validation.Validator> getValidators(java.lang.Class<? extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model>);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder validateRegexpOf(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder validateEmailOf(java.lang.String);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder validateRange(java.lang.String, java.lang.Number, java.lang.Number);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder validatePresenceOf(java.lang.String...);
  protected static org.javalite.validation.ValidationBuilder validateWith(org.javalite.validation.Validator);
  protected static void convertWith(org.javalite.conversion.Converter, java.lang.String...);
  protected static void dateFormat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...);
  protected static void dateFormat(java.text.DateFormat, java.lang.String...);
  protected static void timestampFormat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...);
  protected static void timestampFormat(java.text.DateFormat, java.lang.String...);
  protected static void blankToNull(java.lang.String...);
  protected static void zeroToNull(java.lang.String...);
  public static boolean belongsTo(java.lang.Class<? extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model>);
  public static void callbackWith(org.javalite.activejdbc.CallbackListener...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T create(java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T createIt(java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T findById(java.lang.Object);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T findByCompositeKeys(java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList<T> where(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.ScopeBuilder<T> scopes(java.lang.String...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.ScopeBuilder<T> scope(java.lang.String);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList<T> find(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T findFirst(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> T first(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static void findWith(org.javalite.activejdbc.ModelListener, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList<T> findBySQL(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static <T extends org.javalite.activejdbc.Model> org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList<T> findAll();
  public static java.lang.Long count();
  public static java.lang.Long count(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...);
  public static java.lang.String getTableName();
  public static boolean isCached();
  public static void purgeCache();
}
```

Comment: if you get that error, you do not have instrumentation in your model classes. Can  you do  the following experiment: extract the class files from your jar file and execute this command: javap YourModel.class and then post the results here. This is perfect way to see if your classes are instrumented. I single class will do.

Comment: Added the result to the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, considering you output from the `javap` command, your classes are instrumented. However, there is still something broken with your build, as it seems you are publishing non-instrumented classes to the AWS Lambda, hence your exception. I created a very simple test to run ActiveJDBC in Lambda:

```
  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)  {

    context.getLogger().log("Starting to connect...");
    Base.open("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://database-1.xxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/test", "admin", "xcxxxx");
    context.getLogger().log("connected!!");
//    Base.exec("create database test");
//    Base.exec("CREATE TABLE people (id  int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(56) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(56), dob DATE, graduation_date DATE, created_at DATETIME, updated_at DATETIME) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

    context.getLogger().log("Found records  in table: " + Base.count("people"));
    context.getLogger().log("Found records  in table (with model): " + Person.count());
    Base.close();
    context.getLogger().log("Executed and  closed");
    return "Lambda done executing..." ;
  }
```

When I executed the Lambda, the CloudWatch provided the following logs:
[image]

The line that was logged after a  model was  executed.
As  you  can see, there is no conflict between JavaLite ActiveJDBC and AWS Lambda. You  need to look into an issue with your build.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, there was/is a problem with the build process. I was using eclipse aws toolkit to deploy my serverless application and that wasnt working. I deployed the same code directly from the aws command line interface and everything just worked.

As to why aws toolkit isnt deploying correctly, thats a fight for another day.